# How can I suppress column header output when using mysqlsh?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use mysqlsh but i need to suppress column headers. 
Unfortunately neither `-N` nor `--skip-column-names` doesn't work for the binary.

```
mysqlsh: unknown option -N
mysqlsh: unknown option --skip-column-names
```

I have this version:

```
mysqlsh   Ver 8.0.15-commercial for Linux on x86_64 - for MySQL 8.0.15 (MySQL Enterprise Server - Commercial)
```

I am not able to find other option then using `sed`

Comment: Unfortunately, currently (as of MySQL Shell 8.0.16) there is no way to skip column names when resultset is printed.

Comment: Hello @kgr, I see. I have used workaround at the end: `/opt/mysql/8.0/bin/mysqlsh --uri ${URI} --sqlc -D ${SCHEMA} -e ${HEADER_SQL} | tail -n +2   > ${TMPFILE}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I have used workaround:

```
/opt/mysql/8.0/bin/mysqlsh --uri ${URI} --sqlc -D ${SCHEMA} -e ${HEADER_SQL} | tail -n +2 > ${TMPFILE}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not yet familiar with `mysqlsh` and can't try it right now, but [`--result-format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html#option_mysqlsh_result-format) sounds promising.

> --result-format={table|tabbed|vertical|json|json/raw}
>
> Set the value of the resultFormat MySQL Shell configuration option for
> this session. Formats are as follows:
>
> - table
>
>   The default for interactive mode, unless another value has been set persistently for the resultFormat configuration option in the
>   configuration file, in which case that default applies. The --table
>   alias can also be used.
> - tabbed
>
>   The default for batch mode, unless another value has been set persistently for the resultFormat configuration option in the
>   configuration file, in which case that default applies. The --tabbed
>   alias can also be used.
> - vertical
>
>   Produces output equivalent to the \G terminator for an SQL query. The --vertical or -E aliases can also be used.
> - json
>
>   Produces pretty-printed JSON.  json/raw
>
>   Produces raw JSON.
>
> If the --json command line option is used to activate JSON wrapping
> for output for the session, the --result-format option and its aliases
> and the value of the resultFormat configuration option are ignored.

Comment: Hello @fancyPants, thank you for promising hint, but it is still require additional output amending. I need the raw result without the column header. Anyway, thank you very much!